# Tapestry 4, get submitted value from non-component element

Tags: java, tapestry

My form has a custom element like below, created using custom ajax:

```
<select jwcid="testtest <at> Any">
<option value="x">California -- CA</option>
<option value="y">Colorado -- CO</option>
<option value="z">Connecticut -- CN</option>
</select>
```

After the form is submitted, how do I get the value of this custom html element?

`cycle.getPage().getComponents().get("testtest")`  ?

Comment: if i have custom html element like above not created using tapestry. in tapestry, how to get the value of the above element after form submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a form element generated not by Tapestry, but by something else.

First of all, `jwcid` has no place in your HTML code, it's only used in Tapestry component templates. Second, the `select` element must have a `name` attribute or else your browser won't submit it at all:

```
<select name="name-of-element">
...
</select>
```

To get the submitted value on the server side, use `cycle.getParameter("name-of-element")` in your page/component class.